# Pooling F-Values in Multiple Regression in a Multiply Imputed Database

Tags: multiple-regression, data-imputation, multiple-imputation

When working with a dataset created via multiple imputation, SPSS pools some values but not others. For example, in multiple regression, I can get coefficients, t-tests for the coefficients, t-values and p-values for those t-tests. However, the ANOVA output testing model fit does not give me pooled data for the F-test and its p-value (nor pooled R2). What is the proper formula or procedure to calculate these values based on the information provided in the SPSS output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an excerpt taken from "Applied Missing Data Analysis in R and SPSS" by Heymans & Eekhout (2019).

> The pooling of Analysis of Variance (ANOVA) statistics is not available in SPSS. In Figure 5.8 the table is shown as a result of ANOVA after multiple imputation. It is clear from the Figure that the pooled results are lacking.

The next section provides advice for doing this in R.

> The pooled ANOVA procedure uses the same function as the one to derive the pooled Chi-square value, because the Chi and the F-value are related. The easiest way to obtain a p-value for the ANOVA is by using the mi.anova function in the miceadds package. In this function a regression based formula can be defined to get a p-value.

I would recommend conducting this analysis with R, as you can obtain the results you wish. Here is a link to the [text here](https://bookdown.org/mwheymans/bookmi/data-analysis-after-multiple-imputation.html) which includes thorough examples.

Finally, The authors above use the miceadds package in R to combine F-statistics. The reference manual for the miceadds package says this regarding their method of combination:

> This function (mi.anova) combines F values from analysis of variance using the D squared statistic which is based on combining Chi-Squared statistics (see Allison, 2001, Grund, Luedtke & Robitzsch, 2016)

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response! This is so helpful. One follow up question I had was specifically about pooling the F values that come as part of the regression analysis. Off hand, do you know if the text covers this? Or could I get these same F values by running an ANOVA alone?

Comment: Using R and the miceadds package you can obtain the F statistic regarding the R^2 value of the model. Alternative you could use mi.anova() to fit the model as an ANOVA, which would provide the pooled F statistic which is synonymous with the F value summarizing the R^2 in the regression formulation of the model.

Comment: Thank you for the follow up. This is very helpful!

Comment: I would appreciate it if you would star or upvote my response if you feel it answered your question. Thank you.

Comment: Done! Thank you so much :)