# Proportion testing from pooled single cell/nucleus samples

Tags: anova, permutation-test, pooling

I have a snRNAseq experiment with a 2x2 layout (wt vs transgenic, drug vs vehicle; Wt-V, Wt-D, Tg-V, Tg-D). I have 6 mice per group, but for cost reasons we pooled pairs of samples in each group, for a total of 3 paired samples per group (~20,000 cells per sample). I am then testing for cell type proportion differences between the groups (using propeller, which uses a arcsin square root transformation for ANOVA).

I am wondering if it is possible to regain some of the power of the original n=6 per group by permutation? I would randomly assign half of the cells in each sample to each of the donor mice (i.e. the cells in B365_377 would be split evenly into B365 and B377), run the ANOVA, and then repeat 1000 times. I would have a distribution of F-stats that would be combined as suggested [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/418272/196677), to generate a pooled F-stat. Then I would likely apply a B-H FDR to account for the multiple testing of the different cell types.

Presumably this might underestimate within group variance, but the individual cell counts have not been duplicated, so I am not sure if it would necessarily inflate the significance of the between group differences? Biologically there are 6 mice in those samples, I just can't match which cell to which mouse.